# Change String Name During For Loop

Tags: java, string

I have a string named "str", and I want to be able to change it's name during a for loop,

So like :

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    //add i to end of string name
    }
```

Therefore, the string's name would become str1, then str2...
Is this possible? I tried to search for it but didn't really know exactly what to search for.

Comment: you want to change your string variable name?! at runtime?

Comment: A String doesn't have a name. It has characters. A variable has a name. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: That's can't be done with Java and most languages.

Comment: It isn't possible with Java but that doesn't make it a bad question, guys. Instead of downvoting, take your time and explain *why* it isn't possible to change local variable names at runtime or add new ones.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for an array:

```
String[] str = new String[6];
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   str[i] = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot and probably should not change the name of a variable, whichever the type. 
If you're talking about String *value* manipulation, you could either:

- Instantiate a new String each iteration of the loop
- Use `StringBuilder` if you need looped concatenation

Answer (score 0):

You can append numbers to your `string`. If it is what you are looking for.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    //add i to end of string name
    sb.append(i);
    }

System.out.println(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: He's asking about changing the variable name, not its content.

Comment: I guess you are right.

Comment: It's not your fault, he didn't ask it good.

Comment: I guess he only wants to print the name of the string like `str1` `str2`, and that's the problem, 8th grade home work problems I presume. :D

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are looking to print the name of the string `str` such as

```
str1 : Hello
str2 : World
```

Well you can use a counting variable,increment it with each print and simply add it to the `System.out.println()` statement.

Here is the code.

```
for(int i =0;i<=5;i++)
System.out.println("str"+(i+1)+" :"+str/*the orginal string value*/);
```

The `(i+1)` will give you the actual count of the loop.